# Clash the field 'identifier' in models.py with the field 'identifier' from model 'accounts.myuser'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to make custom user model.

So I tried like this.

```
# accounts/models.py
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        unique=True,
    )
    identifier = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        unique=True,
    )

    # date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # EMAIL_FIELD = 
    USERNAME_FIELD = identifier
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
    #     'identifier',
    # ]
```

```
# test_server/settings.py

...

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MyUser'
```

My purpose is to use variable 'identifier' as username.

but after I typed "python manage.py makemigrations",

then terminal said:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
accounts.MyUser.identifier: (models.E006) The field 'identifier' clashes with the field 'identifier' from model 'accounts.myuser'.
```

The problem is `USERNAME_FIELD = identifier`.

I don't know why this happened to me.

I want to really know its cause.

Could you help me to solve this problem with any suggetion, keyword or something?

Thx.

- pip list

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ---------
asgiref                       3.5.2
attrs                         22.1.0
Automat                       20.2.0
autopep8                      1.7.0
certifi                       2022.9.24
charset-normalizer            2.1.1
constantly                    15.1.0
Django                        4.1.1
django-cors-headers           3.13.0
djangorestframework           3.13.1
djangorestframework-simplejwt 5.2.2
hyperlink                     21.0.0
idna                          3.4
incremental                   21.3.0
mysqlclient                   2.1.1
pip                           23.1.2
pycodestyle                   2.9.1
PyJWT                         2.7.0
pytz                          2022.2.1
requests                      2.28.1
setuptools                    65.5.0
six                           1.16.0
sqlparse                      0.4.2
toml                          0.10.2
Twisted                       22.8.0
twisted-iocpsupport           1.0.3
typing_extensions             4.4.0
tzdata                        2022.2
urllib3                       1.26.12
zope.interface                5.5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

From:

```
USERNAME_FIELD = identifier
```

To:

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'identifier'
```